# How to read a csv file into jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, read.csv

I need to read a csv file of size 450Mb into a jupyter notebook. First I got this error:
**"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 118515: invalid start byte'"**
then I added **"encoding='cp1252'"** into the line but I got another error :
**"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 214809: character maps to** 
Is there another way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to save the csv into new file with a given encoding like `utf-8` or `big5` then read it again? (Suggest to open it via txt application, `NO EXCEL`)

Answer (score 0):

Even if Pandas can handle huge data, Jupyter Notebook cannot. To read a huge CSV file, you need to work in chunks. I faced similar

situation where the Jupyter Notebook kernel would die and I had to start over again. Try this -

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv("path/file.csv", chunksize = 1000):

    print(chunk)
```